# iOS Core Data Group By Issue

Tags: ios, core-data, aggregate-functions, nsfetchrequest

I get the following exception when i tried to use "setPropertiesToGroupBy".

> 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions ((), name p_name,

I tried number of solution on stack overflow but i couldn't find a justifiable reason for the above exception.

So my question, the issue is based on the following dataset

```
|person_ID |  phonenum    | p_name | Paid  
|    1     |     123      | tom    |   0 
|    2     |     415      | rob    |   0
|    1     |     233      | tom    |   1
|    3     |     875      | jil    |   0
|    1     |     445      | tom    |   1
|    2     |     253      | rob    |   0 
|    2     |     475      | rob    |   1
```

I want the result to be grouped by the person id and ordered by paid so i get at least one row per each person being the person who has paid on top.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS GROUPBY person_ID ORDERBY Paid desc 


|person_ID |  phonenum    | p_name | Paid  
|    1     |     233      | tom    |   1
|    2     |     475      | rob    |   1
|    3     |     875      | jil    |   0
```

Any suggestion please shed some light.

Comment: It would help if you showed the code creating the fetch request.

Comment: You need to use withSectionKeyPathName: with your fetchResultsController

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fetchResultsController:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *contoller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:YOUR_REQUEST managedObjectContext:YOUR_CONTEXT] sectionNameKeyPath:person_ID cacheName:nil];
```